# Django prefetch_related and N+1 - How is it solved?

Tags: python, django

I am sitting with a query looking like this:

```
# Get the amount of kilo attached to products
product_data = {}
for productSpy in ProductSpy.objects.all():
    product_data[productSpy.product.product_id] = productSpy.kilo  # RERUN
```

I do not see how I on my last line would be able to use prefetch_related. In the examples in the docs it's very simplified and somehow makes sense, but I do not understand the whole concept enough to see myself out of this. Could I please get explained what's being done and how? I find this very important to understand, and where met by my first N+1 here.

Thank you up front for your time.

models.py

```
class ProductSpy(models.Model):
  created_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

  def __str__(self):
    return self.kilo


class Product(models.Model):
  product_id = models.IntegerField()
  name = models.CharField(max_length=150)

  def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

Comment: Show your (relevant) models...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When one writes `productSpy.product` if the related object is not already fetched, Django makes automatically will make a query to the database to get the related `Product` instance. Hence if `ProductSpy.objects.all()` returned `N` instances by writing `productSpy.product` in a loop we will be making `N` more queries which is what we call `N + 1` problem.

Moving further although you can use `prefetch_related` (will use 2 queries in your case) here it would be better for you to use [`select_related` [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) which will use a LEFT JOIN and get you the related instances in 1 query itself:

```
product_data = {}
queryset = ProductSpy.objects.select_related('product')
for productSpy in queryset:
    product_data[productSpy.product.product_id] = productSpy.kilo # No extra queries as we used `select_related`
```

> **Note**: There seems to be some problem with your logic here though, as multiple `ProductSpy` instances can have the *same* `Product`,
> hence your loop might overwrite some values.

Answer (score 1):

Django fetches related tables at runtime:

each call to productSpy.product will fetch from the table product using productSpy.id

The latency in I/O operation means that this code is highly inefficient. using prefetch_related will fetch product for all the product spy objects in one shot resulting in better performance.

```
# Get the amount of kilo attached to products
product_data = {}
product_spies =  ProductSpy.objects.all()
product_spies.prefetch_related('product')
product_spies.prefetch_related('kilo')
for productSpy in product_spies:
    product_data[productSpy.product.product_id] = productSpy.kilo  # RERUN
```